# I want to add 5 hours on my current time

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to have an output like this 
MM-DD-YYYY +5hours

Mine is Feb 24, 2014 4:05PM
Here's my code

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(hour,5,getdate()) AS nvarchar(30))
```

Comment: Try using `convert()` with the appropriate format.  I don't understand the question.  You seem to know how to add five hours to the current date/time.  And, your code appears correct according to SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15123 (but I would still do `convert()` with an explicit format).

Comment: @Gordon Linoff please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DATEADD (datepart , number , date )](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
Declare @myDate Datetime    
Set @myDate = dateadd(HOUR, 5, getdate())

SELECT Left(Convert(varchar(10),@myDate,21),10) +
       stuff(right(convert(varchar(26), @myDate, 109 ), 15 ), 7, 7, ' ')
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15149)

Comment: I want an output like this for example "2014-02-24 01:13PM"

Comment: The output was "Feb 24 2014 4:22PM"

Comment: are you using sql 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Use CONVERT passing the *Style*:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), DATEADD(hour,5,getdate()), 101)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx